# Evaluating the same object through span relation in qs.excude()

Tags: django, django-queryset

Consider a Hotel with Room objects and Reservation objects for those rooms. I want to find which rooms are available at a given period or (particularly in the example below) from which date onward.

A reservation can be 'deleted', which is obtained by settings the "Live" field. So they're not *actually* deleted but just inactive, and this would need to remain this way.

```
>>> indate = "20141225"
>>> Room.objects.exclude(
(models.Q(reservation__live=True , reservation__date_out__gt=indate) 
| models.Q(reservation__date_out__isnull=True, reservation__live=True))
)
```

**Problem statement**: The above code has an unfortunate side effect: when there is a reservation with `live=True` that is *outside* the period, and when there's another reservation `live=False` *within* the period for the same room, then that Room will be excluded. This should not be the case: since the reservation within the period I'm asking for is not set to `live=True`, it should be not be taken into account.

It looks like my query above is not considering the *same* reservation when doing the (live=True *and* date_out__gt=indate) comparison through the room-reservation relation.

**Question**: is there a way, within the exclude(), to ensure the *same* reservation is considered in the comparison?

I tried playing around with negative models.Q (`~Models.Q`) to no avail. 
Note the above is just a code extract (where the issue resides) out of a much larger query. Therefore I cannot simply do `qs.filter(reservation__live=True)`. Moving over the query to filter instead of exclude doesn't seem to be an option.

**Edit**: adding my simplified models on request, below.
**Edit2**: adding some test data explaining the issue, and adding a chained exclude() as per @knbk's suggestion.

```
class AvailableRoomManager(models.Manager):

    def available_with_Q(self, indate, outdate):
        qs = super(AvailableRoomManager, self).get_queryset()

        if indate and outdate:
            qs = qs.exclude(models.Q(reservation__date_out__gt=indate, reservation__date_in__lt=outdate, reservation__live=True)
                            | models.Q(reservation__date_out__isnull=True, reservation__date_in__isnull=False, reservation__date_in__lt=outdate, reservation__live=True))

        elif indate and not outdate:
            qs = qs.exclude((models.Q(reservation__date_out__gt=indate, reservation__date_in__isnull=False, reservation__live=True)
                            | models.Q(reservation__date_out__isnull=True, reservation__date_in__isnull=False, reservation__live=True)))

        return qs

    def available_with_chained_excludes(self, indate, outdate):
        qs = super(AvailableRoomManager, self).get_queryset()

        if indate and outdate:
            qs = qs.exclude(reservation__date_out__gt=indate, reservation__date_in__lt=outdate, reservation__live=True) \
                   .exclude(reservation__date_out__isnull=True, reservation__date_in__isnull=False, reservation__date_in__lt=outdate, reservation__live=True)

        elif indate and not outdate:
            qs = qs.exclude(reservation__date_out__gt=indate, reservation__date_in__isnull=False, reservation__live=True) \
                   .exclude(reservation__date_out__isnull=True, reservation__date_in__isnull=False, reservation__live=True)

        return qs


class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

    objects = models.Manager()
    available_rooms = AvailableRoomManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Reservation(models.Model): 
    date_in = models.DateField()
    date_out = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room)
    live = LiveField()  # See django-livefield; to do deletion. Basically adds a field "live" to the model.

    objects = LiveManager()
    all_objects = LiveManager(include_soft_deleted=True)
```

The problem pops up in the `exclude()` statements above when there is an active (live=True) outside the period searching for, and when there is an inactive (live != True) inside the period I'm searching for.

Some simple test data using the above models, showing what the issue is about:

```
# Let's make two rooms, R001 and R002
>>> room1 = Room.objects.get_or_create(name="R001")[0]
>>> room2 = Room.objects.get_or_create(name="R002")[0]

# First reservation, with no date_out, is created but then "deleted" by setting field 'live' to False
>>> res1 = Reservation.objects.get_or_create(date_in="2014-12-01", date_out=None, room=room1)[0]
>>> res1.live = False
>>> res1.save()

# Second reservation in same room is created with date_out set to Dec 15th
>>> res2 = Reservation.objects.get_or_create(date_in="2014-12-01", date_out="2014-12-15", room=room1)[0]

# Here I'd expect to have R001 listed as well... this is not the case
>>> Room.available_rooms.available_with_Q("2014-12-16", "")
[<Room: R002>]
>>> Room.available_rooms.available_with_chained_excludes("2014-12-16", "")
[<Room: R002>]

# As a test, when changing "deleted" res1's Room to room2, the manager does return R001
>>> res1.room = room2
>>> res1.save()
>>> Room.available_rooms.available_with_Q("2014-12-16", "")
[<Room: R001>, <Room: R002>]
>>> Room.available_rooms.available_with_chained_excludes("2014-12-16", "")
[<Room: R001>, <Room: R002>]
```

Comment: Can you post your models so we can see how they relate?

Comment: @xblitz: sure! Please see above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it with your github project, and I got the same results as you did. It seems that, while `filter` correctly converts multiple related-object filters to an `INNER JOIN`, `exclude` converts it in some sort of subquery where each filter (even within the same call) is checked on its own.

I've found a workaround for this, and that is to explicitly create the subquery of reservations:

```
elif indate and not outdate:
    ress = Reservation.objects.filter(Q(live=True, date_in__isnull=False), Q(date_out__gt=indate) | Q(date_out__isnull=True))
    rooms = Room.objects.exclude(reservation__in=ress)
etc...
```

Btw, if you ever need to use `filter` instead of `exclude`, the following queries are always identical, and in fact, this is what Django does internally:

```
Room.objects.exclude(<some_filter>)
Room.objects.filter(~Q(<some_filter>))
```

Comment: Thanks @knbk, your suggestion suggestion not to use models.Q makes sense, but it does not seem to fix the issue. The system still evaluates the inactive (`live != True`) reservation. Please see the edit in the opening post.

Comment: @SaeX I can't seem to reproduce those (wrong) results. What version of Django are you using? Can you post the results of `print qs.query` in your `available_...` methods? Btw, disregard the part about nested `Q` objects; while it is true with just an outer join that the left-hand table won't get filtered, the `WHERE` clause of the produced query actually takes care of the filtering. (Yeah, I suck at raw SQL.) While `Q` objects and simple exclude clauses do produce vastly different queries, I get the correct results with both, tested on Django 1.4 and 1.7.

Comment: I tried in a new virtual environment with Django 1.7, now with sqlite (before Postgres) and have the same behavior as described in the opening post. I removed django-livefield (and change to regular NullBooleanField instead). I've posted my repo to https://github.com/SaeX/SO_27548114.

Comment: @SaeX I tested the project in your repo and I got the same results as you. It looks to me like either a bug or some far-fetched logic. Anyway, I've posted a workaround.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the workaround. I was about to play around with `reservation__in=reservationlist` (hence the draft). I'll accept your answer for now (although it's a workaround and no real solution). I'd be very interested if anybody else would know the root cause of this (perhaps a Django bug as you indicated). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want to not allow a checkin if there is already a reservation in that time, or a user would like to checkout when there is already a reservation placed:

first case : R_IN  User_IN  R_out

second case: R_IN User_IN   (the room is considered busy, so no more check ins)

third case : User_IN R_IN User_OUT

```
Room.objects.exclude(
    models.Q(reservation__live=False, reservation__date_in__lte=indate, reservation__date_out__gte=indate)
  |
    models.Q(reservation__live=False, reservation__date_in__lte=indate, reservation__date_out__isnull=True)
  |
    models.Q(reservation__live=False, reservation__date_in__gte=indate, reservation__date_in__lte=outdate)
)
```

if you need to take into account the case where outdate is not available you could simply factor out the last case, handling how it's best for you, maybe removing that room altogether because of possible conflicts or forcing the user to leave a day before the reservation you already have checks in